# Outputting same value for two separate sorting functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Hey doing drills on sorting and I found something that I don't fully understand.

```
let numbers = [1,3,2,5,4];
let sortedHighesttoLowest = numbers.sort((a, b)=> b-a);
let sortedLowesttoHighest = numbers.sort((a, b)=> a-b);

console.log(sortedHighesttoLowest);
console.log(sortedLowesttoHighest);

output: 
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

how come this outputs only the last function's value twice even though I assigned them to two separate variable?

Comment: You can also find more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?retiredLocale=tr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparator function works little different than some traditional languages that you might be used to.

In js, the return value of comparator is -1, 0 and 1. Although in lot of cases you can get away with using `-` minus operator.

Having said that, you're passing array as reference here which is causing the problem.

Try running this:

```js
let numbers = [1,3,2,5,4];
let sortedHighesttoLowest = numbers.sort((a, b)=> a - b);
console.log(sortedHighesttoLowest);

let sortedLowesttoHighest = numbers.sort((a, b)=> b - a);
console.log(sortedLowesttoHighest);
```

Additionally I'd encourage you to go through [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) as well

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are passed by reference. So when you assign to your variable a sorted array and then you sort again, the first variable will also be affected. You can use spread operator to avoid this.

```js
let numbers = [1,3,2,5,4];
let sortedHighesttoLowest = [...numbers.sort((a, b)=> b-a)];
let sortedLowesttoHighest = [...numbers.sort((a, b)=> a-b)];

console.log(sortedHighesttoLowest);
console.log(sortedLowesttoHighest);

//output: 
//[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
//[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```